# Can I use findstr on a filename including * and not get the filename and path in the output?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Here is my search:

```
if exist log\logfile.txt.bak* findstr /I /C:"FAN_FAULT" log\logfile.txt.bak* >>%outputname%
```

And my result:

```
log\logfile.txt.bak4:2014/03/20 15:11:19.894; Info   ;Sending Alert FAN_FAULT_SYS_FANSPEED -  - Fan speed fault;
```

What I expect (and get if there is no wildcard):

```
Info   ;Sending Alert FAN_FAULT_SYS_FANSPEED -  - Fan speed fault;
```

Tried with `?` as well with same result.

Comment: just use a `FOR` loop with `;` delimiters to extract it.

Comment: expected should be --- :2014/03/20 15:11:19.894; Info ;Sending Alert FAN_FAULT_SYS_FANSPEED - - Fan speed fault;  --- without the file name at the beginning

Comment: Actually the colon is part of the file name prefix, so you do not want it in your output.

Comment: Excuse me. In the question you said: "What I expected: `Info   ;Sending...`". Now you said: "expected should be --- :2014/03/20 15:11:19.894; Info ;Sending...". What do you _really_ wants?

Answer (score 1):

```
if exist log\logfile.txt.bak* (
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a in ('findstr /I /C:"FAN_FAULT" log\logfile.txt.bak*') do echo %%b >>%outputname%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `findstr` with wildcards, it gives you the filename in front of the found line:

`log\logfile.txt.bak4:`2014/03/20 15:11:19.894; Info   ;Sending Alert FAN_FAULT_SYS_FANSPEED

This makes sense, because there might be several files.

For the date/time string I'm not sure, my `findstr` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (log\logfile.txt.bak*) do findstr /I /C:"FAN_FAULT" "%%a" >>%outputname%
```